# How to do password-less login using plink?

Tags: windows, powershell, putty, plink

I'm able to login passwordless with putty after adding the key to my server and configuring putty (gui) with session. I'm unable to login passwordless with plink. How do I do this?

Comment: When in doubt, read the [documentation](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.70/htmldoc/Chapter7.html#plink).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `-i` option to use the particular private key or just use `-load` option with the session that you created in putty gui.